# How to change the number of results in jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have this code and I want to add a variable to paged me 50 to 50, anyone know how?

```
$(function() {
    $("#example1").dataTable();
    $('#example2').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});
```

Comment: Provide us with some HTML code and what you have tried so far towards solving your question please

Comment: The code is in php and I do it well. What is paging I want a 10 paged me directly 50. The html code is a simple div where this query php.

Comment: Please try this once 'iDisplayLength': 5,

Comment: I had already tried and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#example1").dataTable();
    $('#example2').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[50], [50]],
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});
```

Comment: Neither works. I do not understand is what it says on the manual datatables.

Comment: Hmm, hard to guess. Which version of dataTables are you using.